Large array average
I have an array of size (1000, 128, 128) where 1000 are total array of 128x128. Now I want to take an average of every 10th array (axis=0) so that I get final array of the size (100,128,128).  I can take all array average with np.mean(data,axis=0), but I don't know how to take average of every 10 array in this case.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers,

You mean the average of every group of 10 arrays?

Yes, but average of every elements within 10 arrays...

If you have 1000 elements:
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1000)

You can reshape to get chunks of length 10 along a different axis:
y = x.reshape(-1, 10)
y.shape  # (100, 10)

and sum over that axis (axis=1):
y.sum(axis=1)
# array([  45,  145,  245, ..., 9745, 9845, 9945])

It's essentially the same if there are extra dimensions at the end.
x = np.arange(1000)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * np.ones((128, 128))
y = x.reshape(-1, 10, 128, 128)
res = y.sum(axis=1)
res[0]  # 128x128 array of 45s
res[1]  # lots of 145s, etc...


If you want the get the average of the first 10 rows, then the next 10 rows, etc. keeping the other two dimensions unchanged, then a canonical numpy approach is to use reduceat.
Since mean is not a ufunc, you can add and divide by n:
n = 10
out = np.add.reduceat(data, np.arange(0,len(data),n),
                      axis=0)/n

Smaller example:
(4, 2, 2) input, averaging with n = 2.
# input
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]]

 [[ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]]]

# output
[[[ 2.  3.]
  [ 4.  5.]]

 [[10. 11.]
  [12. 13.]]]


If you don't mind installing an extra package, einops provides a one-liner solution here, using reduce():
import numpy as np
from einops import reduce

a = np.arange(1000 * 128 * 128).reshape(1000, 128, 128)

result = reduce(a.astype(float), "(a1 a2) b c -> a1 b c", "mean", a1=100)

# Sanity-check results on first group
group_0 = np.arange(10 * 128 * 128).reshape(10, 128, 128)
assert np.allclose(result[0], np.average(group_0, axis=0))


By names left of the arrow ->, we refer to the array axes before reduction; by names right of the arrow, we refer to axes after reduction. Since we want to reduce in groups along axis 0, we write a combination (…) of two names a1 and a2 here, and only write a1 on the right. Since we don't want to reduce values along axes 1 and 2, we simply repeat their names on the right. Similarly, we could have written "(a1 a2) ... -> a1 ...", using elipses ... to indicate that we don't want to reduce anything after axis 0.
With a1=100, we specify that 100 groups should be left after reduction. Similarly, we could have written a2=10, indicating that we want to have 10 values in each group.
With "mean", we specify how the ten values along axis 0 in each group should be reduced; namely, by taking the mean or average (another option would be "max", for example, taking the maximum along axis 0 in each group).

Anyway, the documentation of the package (linked above) describes this way better than I can and also provides helpful tutorials.
For further ideas on how to solve your specific question, you might also want to have a look at the answers on this related question.

You should be able to achieve it by using np.split and then finding the mean around axis = 1 as so:
sub_arrays = np.split(data, 100, axis=0)
np.mean(sub_arrays, axis=1)


The following generates the mean of groups of consecutive subarrays. In the example there are 6 subarrays grouped to 3 with 2 arrays per group:
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(6*3*3).reshape(6, 3, 3)
print(arr)
print()
arr = arr.reshape(3, 2, 3, 3)
arr = arr.mean(axis=1)
print(arr)

Output:
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]

 [[27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [33 34 35]]

 [[36 37 38]
  [39 40 41]
  [42 43 44]]

 [[45 46 47]
  [48 49 50]
  [51 52 53]]]

[[[ 4.5  5.5  6.5]
  [ 7.5  8.5  9.5]
  [10.5 11.5 12.5]]

 [[22.5 23.5 24.5]
  [25.5 26.5 27.5]
  [28.5 29.5 30.5]]

 [[40.5 41.5 42.5]
  [43.5 44.5 45.5]
  [46.5 47.5 48.5]]]

